# fordern vs. fördern: Is there any relationship between the two etymologically?

Tags: etymology, meaning

I have a question regarding the two words:

1. fordern: to postulate, to posit, to demand, to require
2. fördern: to fascilitate, to further, to foster

Is their similar spelling a coincidence?

Comment: Where did you get the meaning of *fordern* from? it's rather "to demand" or "to claim" than "to postulate".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two words are not directly related like verb–causative verb pairs such as *fallen/[fällen](https://www.dwds.de/wb/f%C3%A4llen#etymwb), saugen/[säugen](https://www.dwds.de/wb/s%C3%A4ugen#etymwb)* or *trinken/[tränken](https://www.dwds.de/wb/tr%C3%A4nken#etymwb).*

The two words are related, though. They are both derived from the root that led to the word *[vor](https://www.dwds.de/wb/vor#etymwb).* Here is how the history of these words goes according to [Kluge](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etymologisches_W%C3%B6rterbuch_der_deutschen_Sprache) or the [DWDS](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digitales_W%C3%B6rterbuch_der_deutschen_Sprache) (I have simplified by only indicating the modern forms):

*fordern:*

1. *vor* + indoeur. adjectival comparative suffix *-tero-* (as in *other, hinter)* → [*vorder*](https://www.dwds.de/wb/vorder#etymwb)
2. verbalization of *vorder → [fordern](https://www.dwds.de/wb/fordern#etymwb)*

*fördern:*

1. *vor* + dental extension *þ* → [*fort*](https://www.dwds.de/wb/fort#etymwb) (related: English *[forth](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=forth))*
2. comparative of *fort → [fürder](https://www.dwds.de/wb/f%C3%BCrder#etymwb)* (archaic word, related: English *[further](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=further))*
3. verbalization of *fürder → [fördern](https://www.dwds.de/wb/f%C3%B6rdern#etymwb)*

Comment: Ich denke, es ist passender, “according to Pfeifer” statt “according to DWDS” zu schreiben.

Answer (score 3):

This very old [issue](https://books.google.de/books?id=cfPvAgAAQBAJ&dq=fordern%20f%C3%B6rdern%20etymologie&hl=de&source=gbs_navlinks_s) from 1884 of the well-known etymological dictionary *Etymologisches Wörterbuch der deutschen Sprache* by Friedrich Kluge  states the following:

[image]

Transcript:

> **fordern** Ztw. aus mhd. vordern, ahd. fordaròn 'fordern, verlangen, herausfordern, vorladen'; entsprechend ndl. vorderen: ein spezif.
> deutsche Bildung, den übrigen Dialekten usprgl. fremd; doch drang es
> aus dem Deutsch. ins Dän. und. Schwed. Es ist Ableitung zu v o r d e r.
>
> **fördern** Ztw. aus mhd. vürdern, vurdern, ahd. furdiren (auch fordaròn) 'vorwärts bringen, für etwas thätig sein, helfen'; wie
> f o r d e r n von v o r d e r.

The newest issue of the *Etymologisches Wörterbuch der deutschen Sprache* (2012) does not state the *vorder* origin of *fördern* anymore, but instead *fürder*:

> Aus wg. *furdiz-ija- Vsw. ‛fördern’, auch in ae. fyrþran; abgeleitet
> aus fürder, eigentlich also ‛vorwärts bringen’.

Source: *fördern. In Etymologisches Wörterbuch der deutschen Sprache (2012). Berlin, Boston: De Gruyter.*

Answer (score 2):

This is what Wiktionary says:

**fördern:**
    mittelhochdeutsch vürdern, mittelniederdeutsch vörderen, althochdeutsch furdiren, altenglisch fyrđran

**fordern:**
    aus althochdeutsch ford(a)rōn, eigentlich „verlangen“, woraus sich das mittelhochdeutsche vo(r)dern bildete. Das Wort ist seit dem 8. Jahrhundert belegt.

Comment: So you are implying there's no connection? - That's not correct. Both are related to modern "vor/vorder-": "fördern"=["weiter nach vorne bringen"](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/foerdern). "fordern"=["verlangen, dass jmd./etw. hervorkommt"](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/fordern).

Comment: These questions are never clear-cut. The original ancestors of both words may have been different, but the subsequent history of meaning and form change is *always* influenced by how similar forms are synchronically. Therefore, it might be more accurate to say that the relation was originally absent or weak, and got somewhat stronger over time.

Comment: They are not directly related in a sense that one is only a nuance of the other but they do share the Indo European roots that is also in "vor". For details see here http://dwds.de/?view=1&qu=vorder (and "fördern"). Maybe you could phrase your answer a little more clear.

Comment: The first sentence presents "Wiktionary" as if it were some authority...

Comment: And now someone please formulate an answer ;)